# About Google Play Games Services on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-api, google-play-games, google-api-client

I'm trying to add leaderboards and echievements system on my project about 3 days...

I can sign in to my app but when I try to open leaderboards it saying this:

```
    E/UncaughtException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not configured to use the Games Api. Pass Games.API into GoogleApiClient.Builder#addApi() to use this feature.
                                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.games.Games.zzc(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.games.Games.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.games.Games.zzi(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.games.internal.api.LeaderboardsImpl.getLeaderboardIntent(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.games.internal.api.LeaderboardsImpl.getLeaderboardIntent(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.games.internal.api.LeaderboardsImpl.getLeaderboardIntent(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                      at tr.com.blogspot.etkinlikhavuzu.benimilkogretmenim.Ilksayfa.onClick(Ilksayfa.java:309)
                                                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5702)
                                                                                                      at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10888)
                                                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22541)
                                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
                                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

How can I solve this problem?

I wrote this code:

```
            case R.id.Enbasarili:
            startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(mGoogleApiClient,
                    getResources().getString(R.string.leaderboard_en_cok_70_ve_ustu_basari_gosterenler)), RC_UNUSED);
            break;
```

Thanks for your help...

Comment: Well, `GoogleApiClient is not configured to use the Games Api.` Did you `Pass Games.API into GoogleApiClient.Builder#addApi() to use this feature`?

Comment: I guess I didn't. I couldn't understand how to do.

Comment: Maybe you should go read some of the documentation like [this](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.Builder).

Comment: I'm really I'm searching on web about a day for only this but searching on wrong where. Anyway thank you. I guess I understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking these documents - [Accessing the Play Games Services APIs in Your Android Game](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init) and [Get Started with Play Games Services for Android](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart)

> #### Obtaining the Google Api Client and Connecting
>
> Your game must have a reference to the [**`GoogleApiClient`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html) object in order to make any API calls to the Google Play games services. Create the [**`GoogleApiClient`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html) object in [**`onCreate()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)) using the **`GoogleApiClient.Builder`** class. For example:

```
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Create the Google Api Client with access to the Play Games services
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
            // add other APIs and scopes here as needed
            .build();

    // ...
}
```

In order for your game to communicate with Google Play games services, your client must first establish a connection. You can disconnect the client once your game no longer needs access to these services.

## EDIT:

> **[Implementing Sign-in in Your Android Game](https://developers.google.com/games/services/training/signin)**
>
> In order to use the Google Play games services, your game needs to implement user sign-in to authenticate your player's identity with the Google Play games services. If the user is not authenticated, your game will encounter errors when making calls to the Google Play games services APIs.

```
private static int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

private boolean mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
private boolean mAutoStartSignInflow = true;
private boolean mSignInClicked = false;

// ...

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    if (mResolvingConnectionFailure) {
        // Already resolving
        return;
    }

    // If the sign in button was clicked or if auto sign-in is enabled,
    // launch the sign-in flow
    if (mSignInClicked || mAutoStartSignInFlow) {
        mAutoStartSignInFlow = false;
        mSignInClicked = false;
        mResolvingConnectionFailure = true;

        // Attempt to resolve the connection failure using BaseGameUtils.
        // The R.string.signin_other_error value should reference a generic
        // error string in your strings.xml file, such as "There was
        // an issue with sign in, please try again later."
        if (!BaseGameUtils.resolveConnectionFailure(this,
                mGoogleApiClient, connectionResult,
                RC_SIGN_IN, getString(R.string.signin_other_error))) {
            mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
        }
    }

    // Put code here to display the sign-in button
}
```

See the [sample](https://github.com/playgameservices/) to better understand the code implementation of Google Play Games.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But when I added this ode yesterday It says:

onConnectionFailed:ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{f1c8656: android.os.BinderProxy@3392f9b}, message=null}

I used this ONcreate:

`mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Games.API)
                .addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
                .build();

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();`

Comment: yes, your game needs to implement user sign-in to authenticate your player's identity with the Google Play games services.  If not, you will encounter errors when making calls to the Google Play games services APIs.